# FastAI error rate still at 1.0 while validation and training loss are decreasing

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'm using fastai to run some experiment models. I've downloaded the [Kaggle fingers dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/koryakinp/fingers) and with that ran the code below. What I don't understand is why, although `train_loss` & `valid_loss` are going down as epochs are applied, the `error_rate` keeps still at `1.0`. What could explain that?

````
import fastai
...
fingers = DataBlock(
    blocks=(ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
    get_items=get_fingers,
    splitter=RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2, seed=42),
    get_y=get_finger_label,
    item_tfms=Resize(128)
)
processed_fingers = fingers.new(item_tfms=RandomResizedCrop(128, min_scale=0.3), batch_tfms=[*aug_transforms()])
dls = processed_fingers.dataloaders(fingers_path)

learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fine_tune(10)

epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  error_rate  time
0       2.198208    1.956572    1.000000    00:13
1       2.032756    1.902029    1.000000    00:14
2       1.878275    1.385014    1.000000    00:13
3       1.759558    1.290756    1.000000    00:13
4       1.691477    1.159635    1.000000    00:13
5       1.620937    1.038525    1.000000    00:14
6       1.539983    0.905508    1.000000    00:13
7       1.486607    0.803955    1.000000    00:14
8       1.426649    0.765863    1.000000    00:14
9       1.364154    0.763216    1.000000    00:14

```
````